# Adding rewrite rules directly to .htaccess file

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanna add a simple rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^apply\/? https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf5IrOhg0E_NAGZnOvMuaXhU80sio8bukaWVBkb87eEOa9kTw/viewform [L]
```

my .htaccess file is like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If I add my rule to the last line of this file, it won't work. But if I add it into right after

```
RewriteEngine On
```

it will work. But it will get overwritten.

I don't understand why this line won't work outside of wordpress block.
I am aware of there is a API to add rewrite rule, just wanna know why it won't work for learning purpose.

Comment: "it will work. But it will get overwritten." - What do you mean by "overwritten"? You can't internally rewrite a request to an external domain (as you appear to be trying to do). The directive you posted will result in an external 302 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the file:

> The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
> dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
> Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

Put your code **before** `#BEGIN WordPress` or **after** `# END WordPress`.

However, in the `[L]` flag means **LAST**, so no more rules will be run if that one has a hit.

So this rule will need to be **above** the `# BEGIN WordPress`

Try this `.htaccess`:

```
# Just to be safe, wrap it in IfModule mod_rewrite.c, so that 
# it does not kick in unless mod rewrite is enabled.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^apply\/? https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf5IrOhg0E_NAGZnOvMuaXhU80sio8bukaWVBkb87eEOa9kTw/viewform [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

There is a great tool to debug your `.htaccess` file, it's called **htaccess tester**. I prepared two examples:

[Why it won't work](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=77006730-6d35-467e-8f54-bbd4aabc4cb6) when your rule is in below the line containing `RewriteRule . /index.php`.
✅ [The fully working example](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=9df15b07-da29-42db-ab43-cd5f3dfbbeef) I posted above.